# unlock database files when SQL server is idle

Tags: sql-server

In my development/test environment on my laptop, I can't back up the SQL server database files because the file handles are kept permanently open by SQL server (VSS doesn't work because the drive is truecrypted)

I was hoping there may be some setting in SQL server that can make it unlock the data files after a certain period of inactivity and automatically open them again on demand, but I can't find anything.

I don't really want to be dumping the database out every night because it's only a development environment. apart from stopping sql server before I do the backup is there any other solution?

Comment: Doesn't the built-in backup capability of SQL Server handle this for you? Why not just script a SQL Server backup of the databases?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option is the auto close property `"ALTER DATABASE [dbname] SET AUTO_CLOSE ON"`. According to the SQL Server Books online ([http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682(v=sql.120).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682%28v=sql.120%29.aspx)):

> The AUTO_CLOSE option is useful for desktop databases because it
>   allows for database files to be managed as regular files. They can be
>   moved, copied to make backups, or even e-mailed to other users. The
>   AUTO_CLOSE process is asynchronous; repeatedly opening and closing the
>   database does not reduce performance.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing that will automatically do it for you, but you can detach or offline the database from the management studio or the command line, e.g. by issuing the [`ALTER DATABASE <database> SET OFFLINE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx) via [`sqlcmd`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162773.aspx) in your backup script.

You may want to reconsider a daily database backup using the [`BACKUP DATABASE <database> TO FILE='<filename>'`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) syntax that actually backs up the DB itself, not the file.